# What is that when you view .exe file in a text editor?

Tags: binary, exe

Take [this](https://s3.imgbomb.com/6U6IC.png) for instance. I know it has something to do with what the compiler does but why is it sometimes basic text and sometimes just a gibberish mess?

What exactly is that that I'm seeing?

Comment: It's a binary file in a certain "executable format" that is interpreted by the loader of your operating system.

Comment: You're seeing the data (which also includes instructions), interpreted as text. Since some of the data will actually be text strings, you might see some readable text in there too.

Comment: @Ulfalizer Are all text strings going to be viewable? Should I worry about that as a security problem? (If my code is closed source obviously.)

Comment: @pshahab48: a) you seem to lack basic knowledge, so this is not going to be relevant to you soon b) no, because storing strings that are security relevant in  your program is a security problem, *no matter how* you encode them. If you need to keep something a secret, you may, at no point, hand it out in a form that the executing machine  can decode.

Comment: @pshahab48: Yes, any string literals, e.g. `"foo"` in a C source file, will be in there. Whether that's a security issue depends on the applications. Usually you don't store sensitive data in string literals. :)

Comment: Damn. I never knew that. When I wanted to make password-protected programs I would always just make an if statement and a cin to check if they typed it right. Baaaaad idea.

Comment: *Never* hardcode a password within source code. See https://security.web.cern.ch/security/recommendations/en/password_alternatives.shtml

Comment: @pshahab48: Even if you tried to obscure it by not explicitly mentioning the password in the source, people would still be able to reverse-engineer your code. What you're doing is called security by obscurity, which is usually a bad idea if it's the only kind of security you have. :)

Comment: @Bathsheba What should be used instead? If it's an offline program or I don't want it to rely on my servers for storing passwords in databases how  can I possibly make a password hidden? It's going to have to be in a file or string _somewhere_.

Comment: @pshahab48: It's too broad a topic to sum up here, but read up on password encryption and how e.g. Unix handles passwords for user accounts.

Comment: And no, the password itself does not have to be somewhere. The gist of it is that you transform the password into an "encrypted" form (using specific algorithms), and then check whether encrypting other passwords yields the same result. If it does, then (with extremely high likelihood) the password is correct.

Comment: @pshahab48: there's exactly *nothing* you can do without hardware help or external activation . Your `if` really only translates to a hardware instruction that says "if the last test was `true`, jump to XY". Any capable person able to handle assembler code can use your program in a debugging environment and find out what he needs to modify to simply directly jump to XY.

Comment: There's methods to encrypt programs so you need the right key (==passphrase) to decode and execute the program, but in the end, if your user has a valid passphrase once, the user will have a working copy of the program in RAM, which can be read out and used the next time. That's a bit more complicated though, so this might depend on the level of energy (motivation) that a user that already has a passphrase wants to spend in "cracking" your software.

Comment: The link I give you lists comprehensive alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

That is a text editor, trying to display what is *not text*.

Compiled programs contain CPU instructions and data. Those things have a binary form that is not displayable as text characters, thus looking at this in a text editor doesn't make the least sense.

I'd like to make an analogy: What you're asking is like giving a waffle iron to someone who can *only* understand braille and asking him what the text says.

EDIT: some of the data contained might actually be text strings, which might be displayable. The analogy explaining that would be that on that waffle iron, the manufacturer printed his company name in braille. Doesn't change the fact that you can braille read a waffle iron surface.

Answer (score 1):

> Text editors are meant to display/ edit text files.

What you're seeing is the *textual* output of a *binary* (executable) file. It is not suppossed to be readable by common text editors.

Any executable file contains data in a format understandable by the loader on your OS. They don't have to (and usually don't) have any meaningful *textual representation* of your whole source code. Some strings *may* appear as vaild *text* however that is not guranteed.

Comment: why are they four characters followed by a space and then four more?